# how to format data using Pandas (format the data format of the results of sentiment analysis)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sentiment-analysis

I am doing sentiment analysis using BERT.
I want to convert the result to DataFrame format, but I don't know how.
If anyone knows, please let me know.

The related web pages are as follows
https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html

```
>>> pipe = pipeline ("text-classification")
>>> pipe (["This restaurant is awesome", "This restaurant is aweful"])
[{'label':'POSITIVE','score': 0.9998743534088135},
  {'label':'NEGATIVE','score': 0.9996669292449951}]
```

The output result is output in list format.

Therefore, I want to convert it to the data frame format as shown below. What kind of processing should I do?

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the DataFrame constructor? `pd.DataFrame([{'label':'POSITIVE','score': 0.9998743534088135}, {'label':'NEGATIVE','score': 0.9996669292449951}])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sentiment = pipe (["This restaurant is awesome", "This restaurant is aweful"])
df = pd.DataFrame(sentiment)
```